# What is this bug on my mint plant?

Tags: identification, bugs, mint

I just found a few of these on my mint plants — does anybody know what they are?

They're shiny gold and white. My best guess from the shape is some sort of shield bug, but I can't find any match at https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/gallery/heteroptera/Pentatomoidea/pentatomoidea.html or any other place I've looked.

Location is southern England.

I'm not particularly bothered if they're harmful to the mint, as it's in a wild section and is mainly there to attract bees, but I would like to know what they are…

[image: Mystery bug on mint flower]

Comment: Its difficult to see it clearly in the image, hard to say what it is, but the sideways view of it does resemble some type of  shield bug.

Comment: I think you're right. Try using the Seek phone app by iNaturalist.

Comment: Ah, thanks — I didn't know about the Seek app. It helpfully identifies that photo as mint, but zooming in suggest it's a woundwort shield bug (Eysarcoris venustissimus).